# Reading objects in file into arraylist

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, deserialization

I am having a problem with reading a file, change the text into objects and then adding it into an arraylist.

This is my code for the Read and write file

```
public class ReadWrite {

    public void save(String filename, ArrayList<Sale> buildings) throws IOException{
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
        oos.writeObject(buildings);
        oos.close();
    }
    public ArrayList<Sale> load(String filename) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        buildings = (ArrayList<Sale>)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return buildings;
    }
}
```

The problem is the

```
buildings = (ArrayList<Sale>)ois.readObject();
```

It is saying that its an unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList. Searching through forums about this problem but can't seem to find it

Comment: post your whole logcat

Comment: There's obviously going to be an unchecked cast, but your problem is that you're closing the input stream before using it.

Comment: It's only a warning; ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to do here.

`ois.readObject();` does has return type **Object**; simply because the stream can't know what content is in an arbitrary stream. But you tell the compiler: "I think it must be an ArrayList". And the compiler tells you: "you can't know that!"

You can either check the type of the object using `instanceof`, or use the annotation to suppress the warning.

The more secure solution is of course to only do that cast if the object is actually `instanceof ArrayList`.

Or you can ("safely") ignore this warning here. As you know what you wrote into that file. But if you mess up, you risk an exception at runtime.